# Can not scan with HP Laserjet Pro MFP M130fn (but can print)

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, scanner

I have an HP Laserjet Pro MFP m130fn all-in-one printer. Connected with USB.

> scanimage -L info: device `hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_MFP_M129-M134?serial=VNH7C06822' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_MFP_M129-M134 all-in-one
> airscan-discover:
> [devices]

I just installed Ubuntu 21.04.
Even though I can print with that device, I can not scan with it.
After launching the app "Document Scanner" my printer appears in the drop-down menu and "Ready to scan" shows inside the window.
After clicking on the green button "Scan" I am getting an error window with the message "Failed to scan - Unable to connect to scanner".

Comment: Have you tried installing hplip? `apt-get install hplip`

Comment: USB or wireless? Give `scanimage -L` and `airscan-discover`. Edit your first post to add the info,

Comment: Ran and edited the post.

Comment: @emmiller Thanks for the info. You have a USB connected device and have HPLIP installed. `airscan-discover` is a separate command to run. You do not have appeared to have done that. Please give its output. Also give the output of `dpkg -l sane-airscan'.

Comment: @brian_p airscan-discover's outpout is: [Devices] --- and the other command you mentioned: Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version          Architecture Description
+++-==============-================-============-==============================>
ii  sane-airscan   0.99.25-0ubuntu1 amd64        SANE backend for AirScan (eSCL>

Answer (score 0):

OK @emmiller sane-aircan is installed, as it should be on 21.04. I does not discover any scanner. This may be a possible bug in the printer's firmware.

Remove ipp-usb `apt purge ipp-usb`. Reboot and execute `simple-scan "hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_MFP_M129-M134?serial=VNH7C06822"`

Comment: Same error message after following your instructions. "Unable to connect to scanner"

Comment: I installed hplip-gui and then ran simple-scan again. Now, I was prompted to install a plugin by downloading it from an official HP server. After the automated download and installation, I can scan documents.

Comment: When HPLIP is used it is indeed necessary to install a plugin. However, the person who closed this question needs to bring himself up-to-date with printing and scanning on 21.04 and the role played by ipp-usb and sane-airscan. They are recommended packages. **HPLIP is redundant** (or should be) on 21.04.

Comment: It is interesting to wonder what would have happened if ipp-usb had not been purged. A plugin installation would not have brought about scanning. Research IPP-over-USB. HPLIP is not the answer to everything to do with modern HP devices.

Comment: Sections 13, 14 and 15 of https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting are compulsory reading for Community Representatives.